# How can I create a clean, but linked Git repository for public consumption?

Tags: git

I've been working with a colleague to tidy up some code that was written some time ago. It's all in a Github repository (private) and there are many branches and commits recording the long transition from a single, ugly, spaghetti-code Python script into a much more modular, testable construct.

We now find ourselves needing to expose this later version to the outside world because it's the basis for a paper that we are trying to publish. Obviously we could just make the repository public, but there's far too much frankly embarrassing code - and a few data files that got committed by accident which can't be allowed to leak outside of the organisation - for us to be able to do that.

I'd like to be able to construct a new repository that just contains the release versions of the code. I want there to be links maintained between the two repos so I can then push across later release versions of the code as it develops. Is there a simple way to achieve that such that the history from repo1 doesn't spill over into repo2?

In ASCII art form, I want to end up with two repos that look like:

```
repo1 (private)

A -- B -- C -- D -- H -- I -- J
      \         \
       E ------- F -- G


repo2 (public)

X -- G
```

such that the branches in repo1 and repo2 that reference `G` remain linked.

Note that `A` and `X` are different because the private repo started with just the massive, ugly script that no-one should ever be exposed to and the public repo starts with a README, a licence and a `.gitignore` file.

If I reference repo2 as a remote from repo1, I can push the branch pointing at G across but it brings the entire branch all the way back to `A` which is not what I want. I *think* that I need to push `X` across to repo1 and then create a branch there into which I can merge `G` and push back, but I've not managed to find anything describing that sort of operation and I doubt that an "unconnected" node could be represented in a Git graph. Is there any way to achieve what I need short of just copying the files out from repo1 into a completely separate repo2?

Comment: I would just squash merge G into repo2 then repeat as needed with more code. @Mark Adelsberger below explained everything really nice, in essence there is no such thing (what you call linking) in git, it is all in your head.

Comment: @hidden_4003 - I _know_ about the linking thing, but having that to hang on it in my head helps me cope :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your diagram

```
repo1 (private)

A -- B -- C -- D -- H -- I -- J
      \         \
       E ------- F -- G


repo2 (public)

X -- G
```

The only commit that can ever be `G`'s parent is `F`, because the commit's identity is a hash of commit data that includes "who is my parent".  You could get

```
x -- G'
```

but then the branches don't remain linked in the way that you want.

One solution is to use shallow clones.  Something like

```
git clone --single-branch master --depth=1
```

would give you

```
(F) -- G
```

meaning "`G` knows that `F` is its parent, but neither `F` nor its history is present in this clone.

Maintaining a running history going forward without accidentally pulling in the deep history that you want to obscure is not trivial - so really this isn't a pattern I recommend.

Still, the way to make it work is to create a branch (`public` or something) in your private repo, and every time you're going to add a release (and *only* then) merge (with `--no-ff`) to that branch.  Then every time you update the public repo, you make sure to pull only that branch and limit the depth of the fetch.

(You probably have to include one parent commit for each release; at least I recall that being necessary on the last version where I tested this.  Otherwise git doesn't pick up on the fact that the "other" parent - the previous public commit - is present, and the commit graph doesn't "look right".  I'm 99% sure this is just a tool issue - i.e. the data is all stored correctly - but it still makes the repo harder to use if you don't include the one extra commit of depth.)

```
repo1 (private)

A -- B -- C -- D -- H -- I -- J
      \         \              \
       E ------- F              \
                  \              \
                   G ------------ K <--(public)


repo2 (public)

        J
         \
F -- G -- K <--(master)
```

For each update, you do a shallow fetch to a local repo, *then validate that you only got what should be made public* - because every fetch has the potential to pull in the full history - and once you're sure, *then* you push to the public repo.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a new repository with only the code you wish to release in it.  This repo would contain exactly the same files as your original repo, but without any of this history.

Then, to manage them both at the same time you can add two different remotes to your local repository.  It's a bit weird, because most of the time when you do this the two remotes will share many commits, but they don't have to.  In this case, they will be completely separate, diverging at the root.

But the advantage of adding both of these remote repositories to your local repository is that you can then `cherry-pick` between them.  When you run `git log`, you will see the history of both repositories.

Following this idea might look a little like this:

```
# Move into the old repo on your computer
cd old-repo 

# Rename the default 'origin' remote name to be 'old'
git remote rename origin old 

# Add a new remote repository to your local repository
git remote add new https://github.com/foo/bar 

# See the history of both of these repositories
git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate
```

And then when you want to make an update, starting in the old repository and `cherry-pick`ing over to the new:

```
git checkout branch-in-old-repo
git add .
git commit -m "New feature"
git push old branch-in-old-repo

# Now checkout a branch on the latest commit of the new repo
git checkout -b branch-in-new-repo new/master

# Cherry-pick the commit you just made into the new repo
git cherry-pick branch-in-old-repo

# Push that cherry-picked commit to the new repository
git push new branch-in-new-repo
```

And now the commit you made ("New feature") exists in both repositories!